A geometric Problem related to angle trisectors

In triangle $ABC$ , the lines $BP, BQ$ trisect the $\angle ABC$ and the lines $CM, CN$
trisect $\angle ACB$. Let $BP$ and $CM$ intersect at $X$ and $BQ$ and $CN$
intersect at $Y$ . If $\angle ABC = 45^{\circ}$ and $\angle ACB = 75^{\circ}$
,then $\angle BXY$ is

Draw an accurate figure with Geogebra in order to have an idea of the angular value you want to establish.

This isn't so much about trisectors in $\triangle ABC$ as it is about bisectors in $\triangle XBC$.

@Blue - very well spotted. The question itself is very nicely written to try to distract from that very fact, too... all in all quite a nice little mental exercise.


$BQ\bot AC\Rightarrow \angle BPQ=75^o\Rightarrow \angle PXC=80$
$\Rightarrow \angle BXC=100^o$
In triangle XBC , Y is where angle bisectors meet, so XY is the bisector of angle BXC . In this way we have:
$\angle BXY=100^o/2=50^o$

Or ... Knowing that $XY$ bisects $\angle BXC = 180^\circ-\angle XBC-\angle XCB=100^\circ$ ...

@Blue, The fact that XY is the  bisector of angle BXC  is enough to conclude $BXY=50^o$.

Exactly. ... As I indicated in a comment to the question, the exercise isn't about trisectors in $\triangle ABC$, but rather bisectors in $\triangle XBC$. Once one's focus is on the latter triangle, the solution is straightforward: Bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ meet at $Y$, so the bisector of $\angle X$ does, too. The angle at $X$ is easily calculated, and we take half. Done! ... No auxiliary circles required. :)

@Blue, You are right. I sometimes make a mess of explanation. Thanks for point it out
